# ruby show #{} when nothing is entered

Tags: ruby

```
print"Do you want to calculate your invoice? Please enter Yes(Y) or No(N)... "
calculate_cont = ""
while calculate_cont = gets.chomp()
  calculate_cont.to_s
  calculate_cont.upcase!
  case calculate_cont
  when "Y", "YES"
      <calculations>
      print "Do you wish to continue? "
  when "N", "NO"
      puts "Thank you! Press Enter to exit!"
      gets()
      exit()
   else
     puts "Error: #{calculate_cont} is not a valid entry!
     puts "Please Enter a valid response! Yes(Y) or No(N)"
     print "Do you wish to continue? "
  end
end
```

when the user enter anything else other than YES or NO it will show the text that he input using #{calculate_cont}. How can i tell the user that he enters "Nothing" if the user just hit enter using #{calculate_cont}? can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you are calling `gets.chomp` and the user entered no value, the output will be an empty string. Just put another conditional

```
DO SOMETHING if calculate_cont.empty?
```

Answer (score 0):

i created this method:

## methods

```
 def output(calculate_cont)
    if calculate_cont == ""
      return "Nothing"
    else
      return calculate_cont
    end
 end
```

with this output..

```
print"Do you want to calculate your invoice? Please enter Yes(Y) or No(N)... "
calculate_cont = ""
while calculate_cont = gets.chomp()
  calculate_cont.to_s
  calculate_cont.upcase!
  case calculate_cont
  when "Y", "YES"
      <calculations>
      print "Do you wish to continue? "
  when "N", "NO"
      puts "Thank you! Press Enter to exit!"
      gets()
      exit()
   else     
     system("cls")
     puts ""
     puts "Error: #{output(calculate_cont)} is not a valid entry!"
     puts "Please Enter a valid response! Yes(Y) or No(N)"
     print "Do you wish to continue? "
  end
end
```

this way i can show the user what he typed. :) many thanks